# customUserNamePasswordValidatorType not working with correct type

Tags: c#, wcf

I am configuring the service for message level security, I am using UserName authentication as clientCredentialType. I have given the correct type as far as I have checked but gives error on runtime

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Service' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here is the web.config part

```
<serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="MyWebSite"
              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
         customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Service.UserNamePassValidator,Service" />
      </serviceCredentials>
```

This is the part of the service model where I am mentioning the UsernamePassValidator type

and here is the class

```
namespace Service
{
public class UserNamePassValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!(userName == ConfigHelper.Get(ConfigHelper.CIMSBulkEmail, "ServiceUsername") 
            && userName == ConfigHelper.Get(ConfigHelper.CIMSBulkEmail, "ServicePassword")))
        {
            throw new FaultException("Invalid credentials");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there anything I missed ?

Comment: The error message says it cannot load the file. Did you make sure there is a file there? Does it really have the name Service.exe or Service.dll?

Comment: The website is CertraxIMSWebsite project and .dll is created by name CertraxIMSWebSite.dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you put the validator type in your configuration, the second part is the filename of the assembly that class is contained in.

```
Service.UserNamePassValidator, Service
```

This means you have a dll called Service.dll. But that's not the case.

So it *should* read:

```
Service.UserNamePassValidator, CertraxIMSWebSite
```

Comment: Thanks, I misjudged the second part

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had given the behavior with service credentials a name, but had left the original default behavior with no name and no service credential requirement in the web.config file. Once I removed the default behaviour (even though I had specified the behavior by name against the service contract) everything worked as expected. I guess any behaviors with an empty/no name attribute will apply to all bindings?